# Attempt to execute code removed by Dart AOT compiler (TFA), how to troubleshoot this issue

Tags: android, flutter, apk, flutter-dependencies

I see this error once I install the release apk - "Attempt to execute code removed by Dart AOT compiler (TFA)" on the Material Widget. How do I resolve this?

I used `charts_flutter: ^0.6.0` to implement some charts in my flutter project then tested the project using the "flutter run" command. It was running fine. After completing my project I generated a Release APK with the command "flutter build apk --release". Now I see this error once I install the release apk - "Attempt to execute code removed by Dart AOT compiler (TFA)". How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

charts_flutter: ^0.5.0 with charts_common: ^0.5.0 and charts_flutter: ^0.7.0 with charts_common: ^0.7.0 is working fine. 0.7.0 has been released yesterday.