# When Using a release apk some code has been removed by Dart AOT Compiler (TFA)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to give to some friends an apk version of my project to test it.
**on my IDE my project is working great**, might be some bugs but the main concept is functionable.

They report some bugs that doesn't occurs on my side, so I've tried the **release apk** and when I trigger **some specifics methods** this Error Appears :

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Attempt to execute code removed by Dart AOT
compiler (TFA)
```

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhSWi.png)

the methods that trigger this error are :

```
Future askFriends(String friendName) async {
    print("Send FRIENDS Request");
    print(friendName);
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(await pbd.getEmail(friendName))
        .collection("FriendsRequest")
        .document(await pbd.getUserName())
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": await pbd.getProfilePicture(),
      "friendName": await pbd.getUserName(),
      "friendEmail": currentUserEmail,
    });
  }

void acceptFriends(String friendName, String profilPicture) async {
    var reference = randomAlphaNumeric(20);
    String friendEmail = await pbd.getEmail(friendName);
    String userName = await pbd.getUserName();
    print("ADD FRIENDS");
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(currentUserEmail)
        .collection("FriendsRequest")
        .document(friendName)
        .delete();
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(friendEmail)
        .collection("Friends")
        .document(userName)
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": await pbd.getProfilePicture(),
      "friendName": userName,
      "friendEmail": currentUserEmail,
      "chatReference": reference,
    });
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(currentUserEmail)
        .collection("Friends")
        .document(friendName)
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": profilPicture,
      "friendName": friendName,
      "friendEmail": friendEmail,
      "chatReference": reference,
    });
    _fs.collection("PrivateChat").document(reference).setData({
      "users": [userName, friendName]
    });
    _fs.collection("Users").document(currentUserEmail).updateData({
      "friends": await pbd.getUserFriendsNumber(currentUserEmail) + 1,
    });
    _fs.collection("Users").document(friendEmail).updateData({
      "friends": await pbd.getUserFriendsNumber(friendEmail) + 1,
    });
  }
```

Also When Running "Flutter run --release -v"
concerning the AOT it returns only :

```
c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk_product/ --target=flutter -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true
-Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=true --bytecode-options=source-positions --aot --tfa --packages D:\Willy\myApp\Komeet\.packages
--output-dill D:\Willy\myApp\Komeet\.dart_tool\flutter_build\605851d98f347f3bc8bcbe0b131320ff\app.dill --depfile
D:\Willy\myApp\Komeet\.dart_tool\flutter_build\605851d98f347f3bc8bcbe0b131320ff\kernel_snapshot.d package:Komeet/main.dart
[+15101 ms] [+15122 ms] kernel_snapshot: Complete
[ +198 ms] [ +266 ms] invalidated build due to missing files:
c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot
[ +600 ms] [ +509 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged, InvalidatedReason.inputMissing}
[   +1 ms] [   +6 ms] executing: c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot
--causal_async_stacks --deterministic --snapshot_kind=app-aot-elf
--elf=D:\Willy\myApp\Komeet\.dart_tool\flutter_build\605851d98f347f3bc8bcbe0b131320ff\arm64-v8a\app.so --strip
D:\Willy\myApp\Komeet\.dart_tool\flutter_build\605851d98f347f3bc8bcbe0b131320ff\app.dill
[   +1 ms] [        ] aot_android_asset_bundle: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[ +197 ms] [ +231 ms] aot_android_asset_bundle: Complete
[+10601 ms] [+10568 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm64: Complete
[ +198 ms] [ +245 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[ +101 ms] [  +59 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm64: Complete
[        ] [  +82 ms] Persisting file store
[  +99 ms] [  +65 ms] Done persisting file store
[   +1 ms] [   +3 ms] build succeeded.
```

Writing on read on firestore aren't a problem, since a lot of methods which is using in the apk use Cloud Firestore and are completly okay.

[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEDs1.png)

[My Pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfVDS.png)

[Build.grade[APP-level]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzng0.png)

[Build.grade[Project-level]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXNcr.png)

I've found only one similiar problems online :
[Attempt to execute code removed by Dart AOT compiler (TFA), how to troubleshoot this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606159/attempt-to-execute-code-removed-by-dart-aot-compiler-tfa-how-to-troubleshoot)

So I've tried to delete the build Directory, flutter clean, flutter pub cache repair, and recreate a new flutter project and import all the components of my project. change the channel of flutter.

Also Writing "Flutter clean" give this a Warning.

```
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used
```

I've followed the instructions but it didn't change anythings.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay So I resolve this issue by :

**-changing flutter channel to stable**

**-changing build number**

**-changing the specifics methods:**

it seems that (**cloud firestore have some problems**(not delivering the same result as the project on IDE).

cf : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1857

methods before :

```
Future askFriends(String friendName) async {
    print("Send FRIENDS Request");
    print(friendName);
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(await pbd.getEmail(friendName))
        .collection("FriendsRequest")
        .document(await pbd.getUserName())
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": await pbd.getProfilePicture(),
      "friendName": await pbd.getUserName(),
      "friendEmail": currentUserEmail,
    });
  }

void acceptFriends(String friendName, String profilPicture) async {
    var reference = randomAlphaNumeric(20);
    String friendEmail = await pbd.getEmail(friendName);
    String userName = await pbd.getUserName();
    print("ADD FRIENDS");
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(currentUserEmail)
        .collection("FriendsRequest")
        .document(friendName)
        .delete();
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(friendEmail)
        .collection("Friends")
        .document(userName)
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": await pbd.getProfilePicture(),
      "friendName": userName,
      "friendEmail": currentUserEmail,
      "chatReference": reference,
    });
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(currentUserEmail)
        .collection("Friends")
        .document(friendName)
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": profilPicture,
      "friendName": friendName,
      "friendEmail": friendEmail,
      "chatReference": reference,
    });
    _fs.collection("PrivateChat").document(reference).setData({
      "users": [userName, friendName]
    });
    _fs.collection("Users").document(currentUserEmail).updateData({
      "friends": await pbd.getUserFriendsNumber(currentUserEmail) + 1,
    });
    _fs.collection("Users").document(friendEmail).updateData({
      "friends": await pbd.getUserFriendsNumber(friendEmail) + 1,
    });
  }
```

methods now :

```
Future askFriends(String friendName) async {
    print("Send FRIENDS Request");
    String userName = await pbd.getUserName();
    String friendEmail = await pbd.getEmail(friendName);
    String profilPicture = await pbd.getProfilePicture();
    print(friendName);
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(friendEmail)
        .collection("FriendsRequest")
        .document(userName)
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": profilPicture,
      "friendName": userName,
      "friendEmail": currentUserEmail,
    });
  }

void acceptFriends(String friendName, String profilPicture) async {
    var reference = randomAlphaNumeric(20);
    String friendEmail = await pbd.getEmail(friendName);
    String userName = await pbd.getUserName();
    String userProfilPicture = await pbd.getProfilePicture();
    int userFriends = await pbd.getUserFriendsNumber(currentUserEmail);
    int friendFriends = await pbd.getUserFriendsNumber(friendEmail);
    print("ADD FRIENDS");
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(currentUserEmail)
        .collection("FriendsRequest")
        .document(friendName)
        .delete();
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(friendEmail)
        .collection("Friends")
        .document(userName)
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": userProfilPicture,
      "friendName": userName,
      "friendEmail": currentUserEmail,
      "chatReference": reference,
    });
    await _fs
        .collection("Users")
        .document(currentUserEmail)
        .collection("Friends")
        .document(friendName)
        .setData({
      "profilPicture": profilPicture,
      "friendName": friendName,
      "friendEmail": friendEmail,
      "chatReference": reference,
    });
    _fs.collection("PrivateChat").document(reference).setData({
      "users": [userName, friendName]
    });
    _fs.collection("Users").document(currentUserEmail).updateData({
      "friends": userFriends + 1,
    });
    _fs.collection("Users").document(friendEmail).updateData({
      "friends": friendFriends + 1,
    });
  }
```